# If I "throw new Error()" in a method what is the difference between appending and not appending "throws Error" to the method declaration?

Tags: java, error-handling, throwable

I have the following program -

```
private static void fun() throws Error {
        System.out.println("I am having fun");
        throw new Error();
    }

    private static void enjoy() {
        System.out.println("I am enjoying");
        throw new Error();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            fun();
        } catch(Error e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        System.out.println("\n");

        try {
            enjoy();
        } catch(Error e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Here, I have declared two methods - `fun()` and `enjoy()`

Both has

`throw new Error()` statement

However,

`fun()` has `throws Error` appended to method declaration

while,

`enjoy()` doesn't have it.

But both is giving the similar output -

```
I am having fun
java.lang.Error


I am enjoying
java.lang.Error
```

So, here what is the significance of appending `throws Error` to method declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **two** kinds of exceptions in Java. **Checked** and **Unchecked**. You do not need to add `throws` for unchecked exceptions. You also do not need to `catch` them. This is not a coincidence. That is the difference between checked and unchecked exceptions. [`Error`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) (to be explicit) is an unchecked exception and the Javadoc says (in part)

> That is, Error and its subclasses are regarded as unchecked exceptions for the purposes of compile-time checking of exceptions.

Comment: but still I can add or ommit throws, why?

Comment: @acidic_base The compiler does not check unchecked exceptions. It does not check if you add `throws` it does not check if you omit `throws`. It does not check if you add `catch`. It does not check if you omit `catch`. Hence **unchecked**. Emphasis on **un**.

Comment: `Error` isn't an exception; it's a `Throwable`.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike-  ***Error and its subclasses are regarded as unchecked exceptions for the purposes of compile-time checking of exceptions.*** --- The Javadoc.